# Translate Prototype code to JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

This code is based on prototype and returns all the input elements that are inside span tags that have .myClass as the class attribute so I can iterate each one.
What will be the syntax for JQuery?

```
 $$('span.myClass input').each(function(element) {alert(element)});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 $('span.myClass input').each(function() {alert(this)});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$.each($('span.myClass input'), function(element) {alert(element)});
```

*Note: not tested.*